# Installing wx python in python3

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am running video player file in python 3 that has the following imports

```
import os
import time
import wx
import MplayerCtrl as mpc
import wx.lib.buttons as buttons
```

I get this the first time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "videoplayer.py", line 3, in <module>
    import wx
ImportError: No module named 'wx'
```

When I try to install wx using `pip3 install wx` , this happens:

```
 Downloading/unpacking wx
      Downloading wx-3.0.3.tar.gz (41.8MB): 17.1MB downloaded
    Cleaning up...
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
        requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1198, in prepare_files
        do_download,
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1376, in unpack_url
        self.session,
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 572, in unpack_http_url
        download_hash = _download_url(resp, link, temp_location)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 433, in _download_url
        for chunk in resp_read(4096):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 421, in resp_read
        chunk_size, decode_content=False):
      File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 225, in stream
        data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
      File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 174, in read
        data = self._fp.read(amt)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 500, in read
        return super(HTTPResponse, self).read(amt)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 539, in readinto
        n = self.fp.readinto(b)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 374, in readinto
        return self._sock.recv_into(b)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 769, in recv_into
        return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 641, in read
        v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

    Storing debug log for failure in /home/cc/.pip/pip.log
```

How can I install wx in python3 without incurring this error?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to install python 3 wxpython phoenix.

```
pip3 install -U --pre --trusted-host wxpython.org -f http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython_Phoenix
```

Comment: The snapshots site has an SSL certificate and `https://...` support now, so you can remove the `--trusted-host` flag if you switch the URL.

Comment: In addition, since it looks like a Linux system is being used there are no pre-built binaries available there so pip will need to do the build itself for your system.  There are a number of prerequisite libraries and header files needed to do so, see the list at https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix#prerequisites, and keep an eye on the output of the `configure` step of the build to see if there is anything else needed on your system.